# Why does the coroutine not work in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coding a simple farming simulator in Unity,  as it is my first game. I want to make it so that the turnip spawns after 5 seconds, but it doesn't spawn at all. I will make the amount of time that it takes the turnip to spawn a public variable that I can change in the inspector. The C# Script is attached to the player, which is a capsule, hence the SphereCast. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PickUpItems : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Variables here
    public float reach;
    public GameObject mainCamera, turnip;
    public Text txt;
    RaycastHit hit;
    RaycastHit onFarmLand;
    public LayerMask layerMask, farmLand;

    // Voids here
    private IEnumerator Plant()
    {
        if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.48f, Vector3.down, out onFarmLand, 1.5f, farmLand))
        {
            txt.text = "Click Left Ctrl to plant the turnip";
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
                Instantiate(turnip, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
    void Harvest()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, reach, layerMask))
        {
            txt.text = "Click Left Ctrl To Grab The Object";
            if (Input.GetAxis("Fire1") == 1)
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txt.text = "";
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Plant());
        Harvest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that sphere cast is hitting anything?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I have made sure it has hit the farmland, I even checked with the ‘ground’ layer mask.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the OnKeyDown check in the corutine, what you instead should do is checking in the Update method if the key is down, then spherecast and if it hit something start the corutine, it should look something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        if( Here you spherecast )
        {
            StartCorutine(Plant());
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your corutine you can just wait and then Instantiate:

```
private IEnumerator Plant()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Instantiate( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common coroutine missunderstanding of how their work.

Your coroutine method is not a while loop, you have to build the loop INSIDE your coroutine method.
So instead of checking if the key is pressed, to avoid an infinite loop, we will check the opposite: if the key is not pressed, keep waiting, if it's pressed, do the instantiation.

```
private IEnumerator Plant()
{
    //while the key is not pressed, or the SphereCast is returning false keep looping
    while(!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) || !Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.48f, Vector3.down, out onFarmLand, 1.5f, farmLand))
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    //if key is pressed and SphereCast returns true, wait 5 seconds and do the spawn
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Instantiate(turnip, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Checking Raycasts inside a Coroutine is not the most optimal solution, but I hope you can understand how coroutines works.

Comment: Still starting such a routine every frame is probably not the desired behavior ;) besides that `Checking Raycasts inside a Coroutine is not the most optimal solution` - why?